# Transition from shingles on mansard to roof - Please help

Tags: roof, caulking, sealant, shingles, transition

I recently had the shingles replaced on the mansard around my house, as well as the gutters replaced. The contractors used a ton of caulking to seal the transition. It doesn't look good, and you can see it from the backyard, plus it seems like it won't hold up well.

What can I do to make this transition look nicer and keep water out?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like someone not a roofer trying to seal a leak and does not where it is.   Get the contractors back to do a good job.

Comment: I did get the contractor back. They said if it isn't leaking they wouldn't redo it. Not happy with their service, they send some guy out to give the quote who promises the world but the crew that does the work can't find their ass with both hands. That's why I want to do it myself so I can do it right